# Structuring a project with svg.js

Tags: svg.js

I tried some libraries for diagrams and ended up not liking all of them enough, so I decided to build my own library for my special use case.

I'll need to tell you about my use case. I want to build editors for multiple graphical languages and want to start with a language called FBD (Function Block Diagram).

It looks something like this:

[image: sample image of FBD]

I would omit the shadows for now, but how would you structure elements? I am tempted to use a `group` that contains the rectangle and a second group that contains all the texts. That much about the blocks. What would be a good way to make the connections?

And I would ask how you would structure the code. Would you say it's a good idea to put a reference to the drawing into every element, or should I use the library to find the drawing every time?

Or could I do something even more Elegant?

### Clarifications

I was tempted to encapsulate a whole diagram into a class, so it will be easy to use and maybe even to publish. As of now I was planning to let the diagram class do the creation of the svg elements and everything that is not a connection or a block.

But it should wrap common user interactions like selecting a block, a connection and so on. And it should be capable of exporting the resulting code to json, yaml or something other.

Now is my question, would you rather have a block and a connection class and use the diagram class as some kind of factory?

Or would you say it should be better to have a class for every basic function and another for user defined blocks?

Which of them do you think is simpler to implement?

The other languages I want are LD (Ladder Diagram), logic, graphcet and flow. Most of them are coming from industrial automation, this is because I think I need to offer them for people who can read these languages more easily.

Comment: You write code to paint a few connected boxes. Then you will realize how the SVG code and your logic code fits together. SVG and JS will not be 1 to 1 (except for SVG.js which is a very simple facade to SVG). But with a few exploring cases you will start to see how your program could be structured. The only wrong thing to do, is to plan without writing code. The architecture will reveal itself after experiments and experienced.

Comment: Sure, but in the past I made the experiencte that I tend to do things the most complicated and convoluted way.
That's why I like to ask firsts

Comment: I understand. That is very common. Thankfully you got a pretty good idea about your overall goal. I suggest you split up your project in small manageable chunks. Since you are new to SVG.js, I would write a small function that create a box to your liking. Then another function that takes two boxes and draw a connected line between them. You will probably find that you need another function that places those two boxes from left to right. Make the functions as simple as possible. You could then make an `Array` of objects that contain the arguments your functions needs and iterate over.

Comment: The main question was if i should rather extend primitive classes or if I should rather build a class that generates and manages the svg elements.

Comment: My suggestion is to start out with your own. Only extend when you got a working prototype and can see how all of the pieces fit together. I doubt you will get much out of extending SVG.js though as the lib is mainly an abstraction and simplification of the existing SVG API. If you want to create something that other people can use then I suggest creating a plugin. Take a look at the existing plugins to see how they work: https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/plugins/

Comment: Also creating a “god” class that manage everything will probably not be easy to maintain

Comment: If you want to create an editor, it is better to write it in a declarative way like react.js. we already did it and it is nice. Each block can be component. Also each connection can be a component. For state management I suggest using MobX state tree.